# AngularJS - Click on object, access it's ID & fire a function with that ID as parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to build a web app kind of copy of a simple iPhone layout with just the home screen (showing "installed" apps) and an appstore showing all available apps.

When in the app store and you click an app, I want to access that app (div's) ID and fire a function sending the ID as parameter. the function should simply add the ID to an array, and maybe (if possible) link to a different page.

So far, i have this in my model:

```
var dummyApp = angular.module("dummyApp", [ "ngRoute"]);

.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.homeApps = [
  {id:"1", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"},
  {id:"2", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"}];

$scope.allApps = [
  {id:"1", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"},
  {id:"2", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"},
  {id:"3", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"}];

$scope.addApp = function(id) {
  $scope.homeApps.push({id:id, name:"new app", link:"/#/"});
};
}]);
```

in short, I want to click an element(part of the allApps array), send the addApp function and provide ID (maybe taken from allApps array if possible?) and push it to homeApps (apps to home screen)

This should simulate pressing an app and then when you go back to homescreen it will appear there as it is in the array.

my HTML looks as such:

```
<div ng-click="adApp('3');" class="app" style="background-image:url('icons/{{app.id}}.png');">
</div>
```

Right now I am just sending a static "3" as an ID but you get the point :)

Any help appriciated!

Comment: `ng-click="adApp('3');` change to `ng-click="addApp(app.id)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, just use `ng-click="addApp(app.id)"` for your `div`.

But the actual problem you are experiencing is that by using the same controller for both routes, and not having some shared place to store the collection of apps on the home screen, you end up repeatedly recreating the same set of original apps on the home screen.

Instead, what you need to do is create some sort of Angular service, that will be initialised correctly and then allow adding apps. This will get injected into your `appController` so that you are accessing that same collection each time, rather than creating a new one each time the controller is run.

You can see [a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJfO4zmwv7IZFXXBziJi?p=preview) that I created that demonstrates a very simple example of this.

The guts of the code is as follows:

Create the basic service:

```
(function (dummyApp) {
  var homeApps = [
    {id:"1", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"},
    // ...
    {id:"10", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"}];

    dummyApp.factory('homeApps', function () {
      return homeApps;
    });
})(dummyApp);
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
dummyApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', 'homeApps', function($scope, homeApps) {
  $scope.homeApps = homeApps;

  $scope.allApps = [
    {id:"1", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"},
    // ...
    {id:"28", name:"Dummy", link:"#/"}];

  $scope.addApp = function(id) {
    homeApps.push({id:id, name:"new app", link:"#/"});
  };
}]);
```

Of course, I would probably create some "classes" (well, the JS equivalent) to expose a nice API for manipulating each app, and a collection that allows you to add and remove apps from itself. Then create a `homeScreen` service that exposes this API. But that is up to you. This will get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I tried that right now both with and without ; after the ng-click but nothing is happening still =(

Do you know if the cursor is supposed to change when hovering over an ng-click element?

Here's a link for the project: http://www.pixellife.dk/nordea

Comment: That totally makes sense! Thank you very much for the in-depth answer! :) I will try and expand on it from here!

Comment: One thing I saw in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlvCbnKAH3g) this morning might also be helpful: remember that controller functions are like constructors. They are called with `new` to instantiate a new instance every time they are used. So even though you reused the controller, it wasn't the same instance on both pages. This is different to Angular services, which are singletons and only the one instance is present for the whole application.